# Load shapefiles stored in web page in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-cloud

I prepared a map with QGIS and published it via QGIS cloud free. Some layers are quite big, and the cloud size 50MB limit has been reached. If the layer sources could be stored in my web page --- reading shapefiles directly into QGIS, instead of uploading the data into the cloud server --- that would spare storage space in my qgiscloud.com account.

I noticed that, after uploading all data to the qgiscloud server, one layer's source reads thus:

```
dbname='wmsdkw_hjbbxg' host=db.qgiscloud.com port=5432 user='wmsdkw_hjbbxg' key='id' estimatedmetadata=true table="mexSECCION" (wkb_geometry) sql=
```

How can I tweek the layer source so that it is read directly from `http:/ericmagar.com/data/maps/shp/mex/SECCION.shp`?

Is there an alternative way to share a large-ish QGIS map with my students?

Comment: Webmapping doesn't work that way (with Shapefiles in particular). You could use GeoJSON. This file format can be visualized easily using webmapping libraries and can even be rendered directly on Github. There are many alternative options but we need to know your requirements and the type of maps you want to share.

Comment: Thanks @underdark. After several attempts, I opted to distribute the maps via Google Earth. It has limited analysis capabilities, but is great for visualization only --- what my students need at this stage. Doing this involved saving QGIS layers in kml format, which can be read by anyone with GE installed. I may study the GeoJSON option later.